# Redirect WordPress 404 page to a specific page

Tags: wordpress

I have built a 404 page in WordPress, but I don't know how I can make it the 404 page. Working with a free theme here and there is a 404.php file but what would I need to write there in order for this specific page to show up?

So that if a person writes test.com/djashkdajhjkda it goes to test.com/404 and shows that page's template and content.

I know there are plugins for this, but I'm a bit stubborn and hope there would be a way to resolve this via code.
If it's too complicated to solve via code, I'm happy to take in plugin recommendations.

Comment: If you got the answer you wanted, don't forget to up vote the answer that helped you ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this code on top of your `404.php` file.

```php
<?php
// Here the WordPress will redirect to the page you want with a 301 status code.
// Remember to change the /path-to-go with the URL you like to redirect the users.
// 301 is permanent redirect. 302 is Temporary redirect.
wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/path-to-go')), 301);
// And here will stop the file execution.
exit();
?>
```

An alternative way to achieve the same result it could be to place the following code inside your `functions.php`:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_if_404');
function redirect_if_404() {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        // Remember to change the /path-to-go with the URL you like to redirect the users.
        // 301 is permanent redirect. 302 is Temporary redirect.
        wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/path-to-go')), 301);
        // And here will stop the file execution.
        exit();
    }
}
```

Generally apply this with caution as it is could damage part of your site SEO.

Comment: It doesn't work :/ Only shows a blank white page like that. And I don't need to worry about SEO as it's a private page

Comment: Did you replace the `/path-to-go` with the path you want ?

Comment: @casualminna if you still get white page, for sure, something else is broken your site. The process I show you it is guaranty that is working if of course your installation is working too.

Comment: yes I did, but it doesn't work. Anything isn't broken as this is the first time I'm touching in the theme editor. Could it have something to do with me operating locally?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell if I don't have my hands on code. But 100% what I have send you as a solution, it works for sure. Something else it should be wrong with your installation if you still have white page.

Comment: @casualminna check my alternative approach. This may work for you.

Comment: @casualminna I added extra improvement.

Comment: The alternative version actuallly works, thanks!

Comment: @casualminna if you don't mind, could you please up vote my answer and click the check mark below the voting buttons ? Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: It doesn't work. Only shows a blank white page...

Comment: @DeepSojitra which of the two methods you used? Did you replaced the `/path-to-go` with the page you want to redirect ? Both solutions are genuine and should work out of the box. There's no magic in the code snippet I provided. Make sure you don't have any spell errors. Finally remember to use only one of the two solutions. You may also activate WordPress Debugging to see if you have any errors.

Comment: @DeepSojitra just to let you know, I tested both solutions on my local environment and both working perfectly. Make sure you follow the instructions correct and activate debugging to make sure you don't have any other issue that leads to white page 

Comment: Yes, it works. There were some other plugins or code snippets which conflicting. Thanks. @KodeFor.Me